# Which of the html/css/js is more important to master in the process of front end web development?

Tags: html, css

I know that if you want to be a web developer you need to know all of them, along with frameworks and technologies. I know you even that you should know to slice your designs and maybe have a basic knowledge of photoshop etc.

BUT, my question is: for a while, can you live with only a basic css knowledge(say editing font, color, backgrounds, adjusting margins, padding, borders, using float and positioning etc - just enough to have content to use with you js work) and by knowing only this you can concentrate on learning javascript more responsibly than html/css? Or is it better if you go with learning in the same rithm?

Say you want to get hired, in a junior/entry position, front end developer, will you have more chances with, say, medium js(+jquery maybe angular) + begginer css or the opposite?

Answer (score -1):

You can code websites using only HTML and CSS, it's all a matter of using the right tool for the job and not killing a pigeon with a bazooka.

As for getting a job, it depends on the boss, some of them likes to teach you their way of working, so, not having experience would be good as they can mold you to their liking.

**But**, most of them will prefer a versatile programmer that can learn any programming language/framework as needed, because in the long run you will be required to do more complex tasks.

Do some freelance projects to build your portfolio, that would help a lot during an interview, it's the most solid proof of your talent. Don't worry, once you get past your first programming language/framework, you'll be able to learn new ones in about a week or so.

Answer (score -1):

In a corporate environment people usually pay more attention to technical aspects of development (TDD, BDD, OOP, SOLID etc.), but not so much to visuals. They usually make datacentric applications and corporate users have no choice, but to use the products that are provided by their IT departments (no competition). In that environment it is usually enough to have good, basic CSS knowledge.

If you intent to work in a company, that makes IT products and competes in the IT market then you would have to pay more attention to visual and UX side of things. They usually have designers and UX experts working along developers. As a developer you have to understand and be able to implement their ideas. Therefore advanced CSS and javascript knowledge is required there.

Answer (score -1):

I would anser you question in a psychological manner.
You want to know about the importance of html/css/js in the development of front end web applications.

Now, consider web development with respect to **human body functioning**

**HTML**

It is similar to the **skeleton** of a human being which has various parts some organs and defined structures.

**CSS**

It is similar to the skin, hair covering of the skeleton of human body.

**JS**

It is similar to the brain of human body which controls each movement of human body.

Now again coming back to the resemblence. If you want to create a ***doll*** like web-app which has the structure and look fancy but nothing to understand and respond you must use **HTML** and **CSS** only no **JS**

And if you want to create a **responding, manipulative, action based controlled** web-app you need to have **JS** along with the **HTML**

Now here comes the third combination, if you want to create a **self constructive robot** which creates the structure itself with some logic you require **CSS and JS** . It wil automatically generate **HTML**.

So the conclusion is what you want to achieve is the only thing which can decide what is important and what is not. Although HTML/JS/CSS are not separable from each other. But still it's your requirement which matters the most.

I hope you understand.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so from you answers and further research I found out that you can build beautiful and responsive website with only html5 css3, javascript free, up to some point. So I might think that the natural path to a web dev would be squeezing the maximum potential from html and css, and learning javascript would come as a need.
My initial thought when I started the thread was modeling just the skeleton(html), learning functionality more than styling, but now I see that html css js are pretty much tied up, and you can't really have content to play with js without css.

Still, maybe its because I'm a rookie, but I'm not quite shure about my "eye" on style, my design taste.